# JSP Servlet does not work after using IF block

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

This servlet works fine when without the using if block but now I need to use the if block add some more options.
Please can any one tell me why is that?

```
    public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

            String query = request.getParameter("q");

            String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("pb.txt");
            File file = new File(path);
            fr = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String byPhone = request.getParameter("byPhone");
            String byAddress = request.getParameter("byAddress");
            String byEmail = request.getParameter("byEmail");

            out.println(byPhone);

            String data = null;

            if (byPhone.equals("on")) {
                out.print("By Phone:"+byPhone);
                while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] token = data.split(":");
                    if (token[1].toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase())) {
                        Contact c = new Contact(token[0], token[1], token[2], token[3]);
                        contactList.add(c);
                    }
                }
            }


                out.print("Else");
                while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] token = data.split(":");
                    if (token[0].toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase())) {
                        Contact c = new Contact(token[0], token[1], token[2], token[3]);
                        contactList.add(c);
                    }
                }


            out.print("<h1>Results</h1>");

            out.print("<table>");
            out.print("<tr>");
            out.print("<td>Name</td>");
            out.print("<td>Phone No</td>");
            out.print("<td>Email</td>");
            out.print("<td>Address</td>");
            out.print("</tr>");
            for (Contact c : contactList) {
                out.print("<tr>");
                out.print("<td>" + c.getName() + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + c.getPhoneNo() + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + c.getEmail() + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + c.getAddress() + "</td>");
                out.print("</tr>");
            }

            out.print("</table>");
            out.print("<a href=\"search.html\">Back</a>");

        } finally {
            if (fr != null) {
                fr.close();
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

you can see the if block right below String data = null;

Thank you!

Comment: In what way does't it work?

Comment: @Andreas without the if(byPhone.equals("on")){ } block

Comment: You say it "doesn't work", but you're not saying what is wrong. Is it generating an exception? Is it generating unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: @Andreas yes it gives null pointer exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious way it can fail seems to be when parameter `byPhone` is not supplied on the request, leaving variable `byPhone = null`, causing `NullPointerException` on the if statement.

Two ways to fix that:

```
// Explicit null check
if (byPhone != null && byPhone.equals("on")) {

// Reverse equals check
if ("on".equals(byPhone)) {
```

Comment: Oh yeah, and you probably want an `else` clause on the if statement, around the second `while` loop.

Comment: It worked on using the first if statement Thank you verymuch!